# M2Crypto: read PKCS#7 structure in DER format?

Tags: python, pkcs#7, m2crypto, smime, der

M2Crypto SMIME object has methods to load itself from PKCS#7 file in PEM format:

```
smime_object = SMIME.load_pkcs7('file.pem')
```

I do not see any method to load from PKCS#7 file in DER format. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to load a PKCS#7 in DER format, you should use an intermediate BIO like :

```
file = open('file.der')
bio = BIO.File(file)
smime_object = SMIME.PKCS7(m2.pkcs7_read_bio_der(bio._ptr()))
```

Answer (score 1):

A function `SMIME.load_pkcs7_der()` has been added in M2Crypto 0.26.0.